# How can i convert dynamodb json to json in a Lambda python function

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I have written a straight forward lambda function that retrieves some data from a dynamoDB database but the format in which the data is return is not the standard expected API JSON.

[image]

How can I resolve this problem?

Answer (score -1):

You might be getting a string back, use `json.loads()` to parse your response.

`json.dumps` converts a Python object into a json string.

You can also try this library: https://pypi.org/project/dynamodb-json/ to work with DynamoDB.